# What is the use of logical operator with string

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have used `if(!$url)` but I don't know the exact meaning of the below code in PHP
Can we check string with logical operator

```
if (! 'redirect cart'){
    // data 
}
```

Is it allow to use in a logical operation?

Comment: that will never run

Comment: `Is it allow to use in a logical operation?`->some time yes (in case of comparision) and sometimes not .Check here:-http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It equals to comparing to `false`:

```
if (false == 'redirect cart') { ...
```

Which could be true if your string is empty:

```
if (! '') { // this condition will be met
```

But this makes no sense to write this condition with a direct **string**, this should be a **variable**:

```
$str = my_function() ? 'redirect cart' : '';
if (!$str) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `!` Operator negates the value of the expression. Code like this `$value = (!true);` will return false i.e `$value` will be false. The same happens when you apply the operator to an expression that returns `false`